# How to fix error 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PlayerCarController.accelerationForce' in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

every help will be greatly appreciated. Im making a unity 3D game and my brain cant catch up with the problems that are poping up. I got 2 problems. First one is

Assets\Scripts\Timer.cs(30,11): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PlayerCarController.accelerationForce'

and the second

Assets\Scripts\Timer.cs(39,11): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PlayerCarController.accelerationForce'

I got 2 scripts
first one is PlayerCarController

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCarController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Wheels collider")]
    public WheelCollider frontLeftWheelCollider;
    public WheelCollider frontRightWheelCollider;
    public WheelCollider backLeftWheelCollider;
    public WheelCollider backRightWheelCollider;

    [Header("Wheels Transfrom")]
    public Transform frontLeftWheelTransfrom;
    public Transform frontRightWheelTransfrom;
    public Transform backLeftWheelTransfrom;
    public Transform backRightWheelTransfrom;

    [Header("Car Engine")]
    public float accelerationForce = 300f;
    public float breakingForce = 3000f;
    private float presentBreakForce = 0f;
    private float presentAcceleration = 0f;

    [Header("Car Steering")]
    public float wheelsTorque = 35f;
    private float presentTurnAngle = 0f;



    private void Update()
    {
        MoveCar();
        CarSteering();
        ApplyBreaks();
    }

    private void MoveCar()
    {
        //AWD
        frontLeftWheelCollider.motorTorque = presentAcceleration;
        frontRightWheelCollider.motorTorque = presentAcceleration;
        backLeftWheelCollider.motorTorque = presentAcceleration;
        backRightWheelCollider.motorTorque = presentAcceleration;

        presentAcceleration = accelerationForce * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
     }

     private void CarSteering()
     {
          presentTurnAngle = wheelsTorque * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
          frontLeftWheelCollider.steerAngle = presentTurnAngle;
          frontRightWheelCollider.steerAngle = presentTurnAngle;

          SteeringWheels(frontLeftWheelCollider, frontLeftWheelTransfrom);
          SteeringWheels(frontRightWheelCollider, frontRightWheelTransfrom);
          SteeringWheels(backLeftWheelCollider, backLeftWheelTransfrom);
          SteeringWheels(backRightWheelCollider, backRightWheelTransfrom);
    }

    void SteeringWheels(WheelCollider WC, Transform WT)
    {

          Vector3 position;
          Quaternion rotation;


          WC.GetWorldPose(out position, out rotation);

          WT.position = position;
          WT.rotation = rotation;
      }

      public void ApplyBreaks()
      {
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
                presentBreakForce = breakingForce;

            else
               presentBreakForce = 0f;


            frontLeftWheelCollider.brakeTorque = presentBreakForce;
            frontRightWheelCollider.brakeTorque = presentBreakForce;
            backLeftWheelCollider.brakeTorque = presentBreakForce;
            backRightWheelCollider.brakeTorque = presentBreakForce;
    }
}
```

and the second script (where i get the issues from) is Timer

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Timer")]
    public float countDownTimer = 5f;

    [Header("Things to stop")]
    public PlayerCarController playerCarController;
    public OpponentCar OpponentCar;
    public OpponentCar OpponentCar1;
    public OpponentCar OpponentCar2;
    public OpponentCar OpponentCar3;
    public OpponentCar OpponentCar4;

    public Text countDownText;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TimeCount());
    }

    void Update()
    {
      if(countDownTimer > 1)
      {
          PlayerCarController.accelerationForce = 0f;
          OpponentCar.movingSpeed = 0f;
          OpponentCar1.movingSpeed = 0f;
          OpponentCar2.movingSpeed = 0f;
          OpponentCar3.movingSpeed = 0f;
          OpponentCar4.movingSpeed = 0f;
          }
          else if(countDownTimer == 0)
          {
          PlayerCarController.accelerationForce = 300f;
          OpponentCar.movingSpeed = 12f;
          OpponentCar1.movingSpeed = 13f;
          OpponentCar2.movingSpeed = 14f;
          OpponentCar3.movingSpeed = 9f;
          OpponentCar4.movingSpeed = 8f;



          }
      }


    IEnumerator TimeCount()
    {

        while(countDownTimer > 0)
        {
            countDownText.text = countDownTimer.ToString();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            countDownTimer--;
        }

        countDownText.text = "GO";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        countDownText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
      }
    }
```

Tried to reimport all and trying to find the solution by myself but i just dont understand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The above describes VB.NET but is common to all languages including C#/Unity. Basically you didn't hook something up in the inspector, or you didn't populate a variable.

Comment: You get the error because your variable playerCarController is not used but you referenced the class.. hence it says you need to reference an object...  Casing is important

Answer (score 0):

`public PlayerCarController playerCarController`;
You need

```
 playerCarController=new PlayerCarController();
```

before using `PlayerCarController.accelerationForce = 0f;`

or Make `accelerationForce` static